# Can't enable wireless connection; no blocks on wifi card

Tags: networking, wireless

I insalled ubuntu 16.1 on my old HP compaq nc6320.
I have tried a lot of things since then to enable wifi, but the option doesn't show in the network menu and when checking rfkill there are no blocks shown on the card...
Using addtionel drivers does nothing and using commands to download other drives also doesn't work...

Hope someone can help me,
Greets nitro

EDIT

output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 terminal command

```
02:06.4 Communication controller [0780]: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 GemCore based SmartCard controller [104c:803d]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company nc6310 [103c:30aa]
02:0e.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet [14e4:169c] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet [103c:30aa]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1364]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed a wrong driver. Connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

You can disable `hp_wmi` that blocks your WiFi by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

Reboot after that.

Comment: Did that, did help, kinda :P
so, yes i could enable wifi(at least the options are there) but i can't, because the card is hardblocked... restarted laptop and gone to bios, but there stood, that the card was enabled, a keaboard switch does not exist...

rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Switch #23 here: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_North_America/12428_na_v3/12428_na.HTML

Comment: @chili555 does not work with ubuntu; only switches bluetooth